# How to delete elements by value in a map structure restricted with having one key

Tags: haskell, dictionary, functional-programming, immutability

The main problem is that I'm working **in a functional language with immutable types** so thing like pointers and deletion are a bit harder. I would prefer if this was implementable primarily in Haskell.

Let's imagine we have a single dimensional field

```
[x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]
```

So I have a map with keys being SIZES and values being ADDRESSES because each entry starts from a certain ADDRESS and has a certain SIZE.

```
[(x,x,x),x,x,(x,x,x,x)]
```

I want to be able to add an element by SIZE to a map and then check if the entries are touching so that I can merge them.

Since my map is by SIZEs I have to iterate through the whole map to find the ones with the bordering ADDRESSes.

Do I really have to chose between `implementing a 2 key map` and `O(n) for merger`?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/IntervalMap ? Not marking this as an answer because I can't make head nor tails of the question.

Comment: The merging is the problem and since in worst case the blocks are touching eachother this map provides nothing more than the regular one, although thanks for pointing out it exists. I'll try it out later

Comment: Why not use STRefs or some other mutable type to implement your API? Is there some reason you want persistent data structures here?

Comment: I was told programming in haskell means sticking to immutable types. Isn't using strefs doing imperative programming in a functional language?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, in essence, this looks like computer memory. Do you want it to be efficient? Because you know, "things like pointers" exist and work in Haskell perfectly well.

> Since my map is by SIZEs I have to iterate through the whole map to find the ones with the bordering ADDRESSes.

No, if you store the ranges in a separate data structure. I think for such non-overlapping subsets, there was something called a spanning tree (or as suggested by **@Daniel**, `IntervalMap`), but I'm not exactly an expert on those. Otherwise, why don't you simply hold memory blocks like that?

```
data Block = Block { start :: Int, data :: [Byte] }
type Memory = [Block]
```

You could cache the block length or use a data structure where `length` is `O(1)`, to make merges `O(nBlocks)`.

Sure, that doesn't make it obvious at the type level that they won't ever overlap, but that's an invariant you can keep for yourself.

Comment: Pointers do not have the same meaning in Haskell as in C++ for instance because the thing they are pointing to is unmutable. Maybe it was unclear but I was already using a O(nBlocks).

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic [are](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html) [you](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html) [sure](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-IORef.html)?

Comment: Aren't the IO and FFI links supposed to be avoided unless neccessary since they are a neccessary evil?

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic You were the one saying that the performance of your solution is unsatisfactory. Why optimize if you don't need performance? Also there are other, high level abstractions for mutable data, like `STM`.